# Watermark.js increases image size

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, watermark

Trying to do image optimization(reduce the image size) and add watermaker to multiple images before uploading to cloud env(S3).

Approaches:

1. **browser-image-compression** - Used browser-image-compression image optimization working perfectly, but watermark unable to add.
2. **watermark.js** - Used watermark.js without image optimization, the size of image getting increased to 2x.

> ```
>  const compressedFile = await imageCompression(file, options)
> let compressedFile1 = await watermark([compressedFile]).blob(watermark.text.center('watermark.js',
>  '300px serif', '#fff', 0.5))
> ```

Performance is also the key aspect of both operations.

Don't want to perform any image manipulation serverside or in a cloud environment(serverless image manipulation).

**Any idea on how to add a watermark and also, optimize the image without losing the quality of the image?**

Thanks

Comment: You said you cannot add watermark after image optimization, but can you add watermark THEN optimize ?

Comment: Sry. I tried both approaches first using optimization and then watermark and vice versa. but the size of the image is increasing. Quality of image decreasing if we using both libs.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar use case where users need to take pictures and then these have to be uploaded to a server with a watermark.

First, I add the watermark and then I change the format to JPEG, which has good quality and does not take as much space as the PNG output of watermarkJS.

This is the function called on the output of the watermark (as dataURL):

```
async convertImageToJpeg(image):Promise<string>{
    return new Promise(function (resolved,rejected) {
      var i = new Image();
      i.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = i.width;
        canvas.height = i.height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(i,0,0);
        var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.3);
        resolved(dataUrl);
      }
      i.src = image;
    })
  }
```